# Is it possible to use dual monitors with DisplayPort and HDMI in 16.04?

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, dell, hdmi, displayport

I have a Dell Optiplex 3040 and it is equipped with a HDMI and a Display Port, I want to use dual monitors and I was wondering if it's possible. The desktop has onboard graphics with those two outputs and I've seen some people recommending nvidia drivers however, I'm not sure if I'm supposed to use them without nvidia hardware. Is is possible to still do this in 16.04 or any earlier versions where it would be stable? Currently I'm using a DisplayLink dock which is really buggy and freezes often, thanks.